# How to add a new locale to macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, command-line, catalina, settings

On System Preferences, Language and Region, when I select United Kingdom the output of `locale` is

```
LANG="en_GB"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB"
LC_CTYPE="en_GB"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB"
LC_TIME="en_GB"
LC_ALL=
```

If I select Norway though the outputs is

```
LANG="en_NO"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

I suspect this is the reason why commands like `ls` show dates in the `mon date` format instead of `date mon`, even when Norwegian follows the latter. `locale -a | grep en_NO` shows nothing and I guess that's why. So I tried to copy `/usr/share/locale/no_NO` to `/usr/share/locale/en_NO` and change it to suite my needs and of course I receive `mkdir: en_NO: Operation not permitted` because the system volume is mounted as read only on Catalina. So, is there any way I can add my own locale?

Comment: Would putting `export LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"` etc in your `~/.zshrc` work for you?

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work, no matter what `locale` keeps showing me that `LC_TIME` is `C`. Also I wanted to get all the values for `LC_*` from `defaults read NSGlobalDomain AppleLocale`

Comment: You need to run `source ~/.zshrc` or open a new terminal emulator window after changing the file...

Comment: Yeah, I know that. Actually I don't use ZSH, I use Fish as my shell, and it's already fairly customised and everything works as expected, except this

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your issue was identical to mine, but this worked for me at least. 
I also noticed that my system tried to set nb_no.UTF-8 (and failed) instead of no.NO.

1. `vim ~/.config/fish/config.fish`
2. `set -x LC_ALL no_NO.UTF-8`

Comment: Not the same, I want `en_NO`, with is no available in the system, so the question is about how to add it first

Answer (score 1):

### Procedure from my cookbook to add a new locale

This works on MacOS 12.5 Monterrey over Macs with SIP (System Integrity Protection), M1 chip:

First of all check if regionality exists in the system:

```bash
locale -a | grep en_NO
```

If there are no results, regionality does not exist. It's no use making a copy because the root is mounted read-only and SIP doesn't allow you to modify it. Although there is the possibility of writing to it, it will not be possible to use SIP again so that the changes persist. localedef doesn't work either. The solution is to create a home folder and change the path where glibc looks for the locales:

```bash
mkdir ~/.locale
cp -rpf /usr/share/locale/en_GB.UTF-8 ~/.locale/en_NO.UTF-8
export PATH_LOCALE=~/.locale
export LC_ALL=en_NO.UTF-8
```

Now the system will have the corresponding regionality. The following lines could be added to the ˜/.profile file so that changes in the terminal take permanent effect:

```bash
export PATH_LOCALE=~/.locale
export LC_ALL=en_NO.UTF-8
```

If on the other hand locale exists on the system (if locale -a | grep en_does NOT return a result) it only achieves the following:

```bash
export LC_ALL=en_NO.UTF-8
```

In the same way this line can be in ˜/.profile. In my case I use es_AR based on locale provided by the system es_ES. It is the cleanest solution (and I think the correct one) that I have found so far without intervening the system.

Comment: Is `/usr/local/share/locale` an alternative to a user-specific installation?

Comment: @gidds Yes it is a good alternative too. While is to whole users, not for user specific.